# Connection refused: connect

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

My objective is to upload the report files from server to Google Drive automatically everyday. I am new to Google Drive API programs. When i try to execute the sample program given at Quickstart: Run a Drive App in Java, i am getting the below error message after entering the authorization code. Request you please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)  at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:564)
>     at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:272)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:895)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:299)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:147)
>     at DriveCommandLine.main(DriveCommandLine.java:43)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a different approach to this, why don't you just install and use Google's Drive app for Windows or Mac?

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive?pli=1

it uses OAuth2 for authentication and can be scoped down to only sync certain folders.

Comment: Thanks Jay for suggesting an alternative option. Is it possible to install the Google's Drive app in UNIX Server?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not. Drive app is Windows and Mac only (though a Linux client is supposed to be out at some point I think). If you could map the Unix directory to a Windows or Mac machine they may be able to do the upload for you.

Comment: Thanks Jay for your prompt response. Will try this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a firewall issue based on that error. Can you try logging in to drive.google.com from the machine running the Java script? Can that machine ping www.googleapis.com? What Internet restrictions does it have in place?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Seems it is a firewall issue. I unable to ping www.googleapis.com and getting the message as "Destination host unreachable."